# How to update an UpdatePanel with a trigger control from outside of it

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have the following button which is outside of the `UpdatePanel` that I would like use to update:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btnExport" ClientIDMode="Static" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="SubmitAdminMessage" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMessages" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    upMessages.Triggers.Add(new AsyncPostBackTrigger()
    {
        ControlID = btnSubmit.UniqueID,
    });

    PopulateMessageGV(); //this displays the message on refresh of the page
}

protected void SubmitAdminMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hostWeb = Page.Request["SPHostUrl"];

    using (var context = new ClientContext(hostWeb))
    {
        var hostSite = context.Web;
        context.Load(hostSite, s => s.Title);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        var allLists = hostSite.Lists;
        var messageList = allLists.GetByTitle("AdminMessage");
        var itemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        var newMessage = messageList.AddItem(itemCreationInformation);
        newMessage["Message"] = tbMessage.Text;
        newMessage["Active"] = cbIsActive.Checked.ToString();
        newMessage.Update();

        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

The following function updates the messages on page refresh:

```
protected void PopulateMessageGV()
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection filteredItems = null;
    var hostWeb = Page.Request["SPHostUrl"];

    using (var context = new ClientContext(hostWeb))
    {
        var hostSite = context.Web;
        context.Load(hostSite, s => s.Title);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        var allLists = hostSite.Lists;
        var messageList = allLists.GetByTitle("AdminMessage");
        context.Load(messageList);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        MessageListCountLabel.Text = messageList.ItemCount.ToString();
        ListUrlHyperLink.NavigateUrl = hostWeb + "/Lists/AdminMessage";
        try
        {
            var query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            var allItems = messageList.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(allItems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var item in allItems)
            {
                DataTable dt;
                if (item["Active"].ToString() == "True")
                {
                    msItem.Add(item["Created"].ToString() + " " + item["Message"].ToString());
                }
            }
            msItem.ToArray();
            foreach (var list in msItem)
            {
                lblMessage.Text += list + "<br />";
            }
            upMessages.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }

        try
        {
            var query = new CamlQuery();
            var camlViewXml = string.Format(@"<View><Query><Where><Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Active'/><Value Type='Boolean'>
                {0}</Value></Eq></Where>
                </Query></View>", "False");
            query.ViewXml = camlViewXml;
            filteredItems = messageList.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(filteredItems, items => items.Include(
            item => item["ID"], item => item["Created"],
            item => item["Message"]));
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I modify my code so that when the submit button is pressed the `lblMessage` is updated without having to refresh the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use external triggers like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btnExport" ClientIDMode="Static" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="SubmitAdminMessage" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMessages" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Notice the [`Triggers`](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers) section

Comment: I have to call `PopulateMessageGV` somehow because the `btnSubmit` is just adding the data only?

Comment: I get this error: `Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A control with ID 'btnSubmit' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'upMessages'.` I already tried that before and didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: if the markup is exactly as you show it, it should work. You may be simplifying the code here...

Comment: The code is as it should be :/. I just checked another question and it is saying I need to add the button to it's own UpdatePanel?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: it's been very long since last time I used a `UpdatePanel`. Give it a try and tell me how it goes :)

Comment: I just did and I received the error. It seems the `FillDropDown` has to be triggered which updates the `lblMessage`. Is there anyway to call that without doing a full postback?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: from my knowledge, that code should work. Why don't you create a new page and test a simpler scenario (if possible)

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thanks. The button which I am trying to use as a trigger opens from a DIV which is hidden and displayed with another button. Maybe that's why?

Comment: It seems the UpdatePanel is updated but the entry is not displayed UNTIL the page is refreshed :/

Comment: I did a Debug and it only works when the page is refreshed!!! No matter what, it leaves out the last entry for the UpdatePanel :/